# The Object That I'm Trying To Get To Move Is Smearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

Right now I'm trying to get the food object to move around. Can anyone help me figure out why? I'm using SDL and c++ the object moves successfully but in the process its smears.
This is my code here.
And when I mean smear it's like it adds more squares behind it making it look like it's smearing. I don't know.

```
void create_Rect(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, int x, int y, int w, int h, int colorRed, int colorGreen, int colorBlue, int colorA)
{
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = x;
    r.y = y;
    r.w = w;
    r.h = h;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue, colorA);

    // Render rect
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);

    // Render the rect to the screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

}



void input(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    Food food = { 15, 15, 200, 200 };// stuct for food object
    while (isRunning)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            create_Rect(renderer, food.x_Pos, food.y_Pos, food.Height, food.Width, 0, 0, 255, 255);// the food object

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                isRunning = false;
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    food.x_Pos -= 15;
                    cout << "Crouiser1" << endl;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    food.y_Pos -= 15;
                    cout << "Crouiser2" << endl;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    food.x_Pos += 15;
                    cout << "Crouiser3" << endl;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    food.y_Pos += 15;
                    cout << "Crouiser4" << endl;
                    break;
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_Delay(1);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've not used SDL but I'd guess you need to clear and redraw the screen for each frame

Comment: @AlanBirtles but when i do that the screen just becomes blue, the color of the object.

Comment: [As the documentation states](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear), you need to set the draw color to something else before calling SDL_RenderClear.

Comment: @Botje when i try to do that it just makes the screen 1 color.

Comment: That is exactly the purpose. You need to call SDL_RenderClear with your background color set, then call SDL_RenderFillRect with your object color set.

Comment: @Botje wow I don't know what happened but now it's flashing when I have my mouse over it. also, the objects are appearing.

Comment: @Botje Thanks I think I figured it out. It's because I had more than one object and I was using them in a function so it was clearing it for those objects but not for what I wanted.